# PHP preg_split ignore escaped sequence

Tags: php, regex, split

How can I split string one by one but ignoring escaped character ?
Here my example, I have string :-

```
\ntest\rtest\n
```

I want it to be like this :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => \n
    [1] => t
    [2] => e
    [3] => s
    [4] => t
    [5] => \r
    [6] => t
    [7] => e
    [8] => s
    [9] => t
    [10] => \n
)
```

Someone said use preg_split, but i don't know much about regex.

Comment: why use preg_match..use string function `str_split`

Comment: sorry, my mistake, actually want to write "preg_split"

Comment: Char-by-char would be enough, with some additional handling when '\' encountered.

Comment: given string is in double quotes `"` or in single quotes `'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backslashes need escaping in RegEx.
When referencing one actual backslash you'll need a series of three `\\\`

**RegEx match**

```
preg_match_all("/\\\?[^\\\]/", $str, $matches);
```

Live demo code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/FLjH9A

**RegEx split** *- just for educational purposes, as match is more appropriate in this case*

```
$matches=preg_split("/(?<=\\\[^\\\])(?!$)|(?<=[^\\\])(?!$)/", $str);
```

Live demo code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/yrbtMV

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the escaped characters of choice first and then apply `str_split()`:

```
$str = "\ntest\rtest\n";

print_r(str_split(strtr($str, array(
    '\r' => '', 
    '\n' => '',
))));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to get the array, you can read the string with char one by one.
no matter about regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match each single character (optionally preceded by a `\`), you can use:

```
$str = '\ntest\rtest\n';
preg_match_all('/\\\?[a-zA-Z]/', $str, $matches);
```

Which would return an array with both the single and escaped character sequences.

Comment: thanks, but that regex look like didn't work for my example string

Comment: Woops, I meant `preg_match_all()`, not `preg_split()`. Glad you found your answer!