# JS regex matching ' but not \'

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace the simple quotes in a string but not the escaped ones (in JavaScript). For example I want this string:

```
'Hello there! I\'m \'Doug\''
```

To become:

```
"Hello there! I\'m \'Doug\'"
```

**NOTE**: I made a lots of research and test (e.g on regex101.com) and found some things such as [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) but still can't figure out how to build a proper regex.

**THINGS I TRIED**:

- `/[^\\]'/g`
- `/\\{0}'/g`
- `/[\\]{0}'/g`
- ...

Comment: `JS regex matching “ but not \”` but the input contains only single quotes.

Comment: Why `'` in I'm isn't replaced?

Comment: `s/^'/"/` and `s/'$/"/`

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Because it's not escaped?

Comment: yep, he want to replace all the `'`  except the one's which are preceded by a \

Comment: Why doesn't it become `"Hello there! I"m \'Doug\'"`?

Comment: @Sam That's precisely what Avinash asked 6 comments ago.

Comment: @AvinashRaj my bad, just a mystake. I edited my question.

Comment: @Sam my bad, fixed the typo.

Comment: What should happen if the backslash before `'` is "escaped" with another backslash?

Comment: @Oriol good point! In my case the only character that can get escaped is the simple quote so `\\'` would stay `\\'`. In an other situation it would have become `\"` I guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP preg\_split ignore escaped sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456055/php-preg-split-ignore-escaped-sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `String#replace` with `callback` function:

```
str = "'Hello there! I\\'m \\'Doug\\''";
str = str.replace(/(\\)?'/g, function($0, $1) {
   return ($1) ? "\\'" : '"';
});
console.log( str );
//=> "Hello there! I\'m \'Doug\'"
```

Comment: A bit weird and my strings doesn't contain a double \ to escape a simple quote.

Comment: It is not double quote if you print it, it will show only single \

Comment: Yes sure but your original string contains a double backslash, not mine. My example is `'Hello there! I\'m \'Doug\''` not `'Hello there! I\\'m \\'Doug\\''`

Comment: You're mistaken. Use `alert("'Hello there! I\'m \'Doug\''")` to see what gets printed.

Comment: This is what I am trying to tell you. [See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbwy757f/1/) and see what first `console.log(str)` prints i.e. no / in the output.

Comment: The console does not print it but it still exist in the string. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbwy757f/2/

Comment: That is **exactly** what I have been saying. Creating string in Javascript will need double / but getting it from HTML will be fine with single /. **[See my working code here](http://jsfiddle.net/mbwy757f/3/)** which prints **`"I\'m doug!"`**

Comment: My bad, you was right! It's actually a bit strange but now I get it :) Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is close:

```
subject.replace(/^'|([^\\])'/g, '$1"')
```

It won't catch two apostrophes in a row, but I suppose you could just run it twice.

Comment: Thank you but what if the string contains X apostrophes? How much times will I have to run it? Seems like there is probably a best way to do this.

Comment: If it contains X apostrophes, you'll have to run it twice.  It will replace every other one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, javascript besides all its portability and power doesn't support lookbehinds.

I made a regex to work well in the case of having multiple apostrophes too:

```
^'|[^\\](')[']+|([^\\])'
```

Replace with `$1"`

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/iU7cA8/3)

Comment: You're getting closer but `"Hello there! I\''''''m \'Doug\'"` should result in `"Hello there! I\'"""""m \'Doug\'"`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need just this:

```
var text = "'Hello there! I'm \'Doug\''"; 
text.replace(/^\'|'$/g, '"')
```